# Call pthread_create from outside main function

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

I want to do something like this:

```
void *do_work_son(void *data)
{            
    mystruct *d = (mystruct*)data;
    while(true)
    {
        // d->whatever is corrupt
    }
}

void start_thread(pthread_t *mt)
{
    mystruct data = ...;
    pthread_create(&(*mt), NULL, do_work_son, (void *)&data);
}

int main()
{
    pthread mt;
    start_thread(&mt);
    // do more stuff here
    pthread_join(mt, NULL);
}
```

The idea is spawn off some threads and keep doing more work in `main`... then when done doing more work, wait for the threads to finish.

It compiles fine, but the `data` struct is corrupted when it gets accessed inside `do_work_son`.  I think this is because the threads are exiting, even though I'm calling join in `main`.  If I move the `pthread_{create,join}` calls both to start_thread, it works fine, but then my main function is blocked by the while loop.  Am I crazy for doing it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple: you are passing a reference of a local variable and then leaving the scope. Replace it with data allocated on heap and it would work like a charm

```
void start_thread(pthread_t *mt)
{
    mystruct *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    ...;
    pthread_create(mt, NULL, do_work_son, data);
}
```

EDIT:

About preassignment question:

```
void start_thread(pthread_t *mt)
{
    mystruct local_data = {...};
    mystruct *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    *data = local_data;
    ...;
    pthread_create(mt, NULL, do_work_son, data);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you just used `malloc()` **correctly.** Rare diamond nowadays on SO.

Comment: Is there a way to initialize mystruct with values as well as do the malloc all in one step?

Comment: @g33kz0r in two, if your data is POD: you can always make an assignment from some pre-created structure (static, local, other): `*data = my_preset_data`.

Comment: My code works now, thanks.  I think you should change `sizeof(*data)` to `sizeof(data)`.

Comment: @g33kz0r Surprise, surprise :P

Comment: I guess reputation *is* everything :)

Comment: @g33kz0r Too bad C is not as popular as its sharp version or even JavaScript, I'm envious of the 100k elite :P Seriously, it **isn't.** Valeri just gave an answer that's free of all errors a typical 400-rep user would have made. Hats off.

Comment: I'm more of a python guy myself.  Came back to C this week intentionally as an exercise in forcing myself to take computing seriously again.

Comment: @g33kz0r Now that attitude itself is worth an upvote to your comment.

Comment: Thanks, your help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: @g33kz0r Welcome. I heartly recommend re-reading a good C tutorial or K&R if your intentions are serious.

Answer (score 5):

> I think this is because the threads are exiting,

No, that's because `data` is an automatic variable in the `start_thread()` function, which is invalidated when `start_thread()` returns, so using its address afterwards invokes undefined behavior.

Either `malloc()`ate some memory for it, or make it static, or whatever. Just make sure it survives the death of `start_thread()`.

Comment: I type too slow :( Off topic: I liked your old photo better ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer I've been typing *a lot* these days (implementing a scripting language). To the photo: I wished *that certain "someone"* will like it. Too bad she didn't...

Comment: @DanielFischer But it will persist nevertheless, maybe there are people who are wondering who the heck this H2CO3 guy is. :P

Comment: @H2CO3 Are you saying that the `malloc` can occur in `start_thread` and it will survive after scope leaves `start_thread`?

Comment: @H2CO3 One additional question:  is this one specific case of the correct use of `malloc`?  Can you give me a litmus test for when the use of `malloc` is appropriate over other methods?  Thanks

Comment: @g33kz0r I was not referring to the use case. I was referring to the fact that Valeri did **not** cast its return value and used `sizeof(*pointer)` instead of the dangerous `sizeof(typename)`.

Comment: What I meant is, as a C programmer, when do I know the correct time to use `malloc`?

Comment: @g33kz0r Never, unless needed.

Comment: Lol.  You're just being short because I accepted val's answer instead of yours.  `sizeof(*pointer)` seems circular when that pointer is being defined by this statement.